# How can i recover css file from dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I am working on css file in dreamweaver, Suddenly power gone. After power comes then  I open the  css file and its is showing blank. I almost lost huge css code. How can i recover this file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mac it would be worth trying the Time Machine, just a suggestion. If not then take it as a lesson to back up often, and then some.

Comment: yes! you are right sir. I am using windows 7. Really dreamweaver is a very bad software

Comment: I transitioned from Dreamweaver to Sublime Text 3, recommend you trying it out if you are dissatisfied.